# Laravel AJAX requests via API Controller / Passport

Tags: laravel, api, laravel-passport

Most of the requests like ChangePass, Create Blog, Update Blog and etc. are done via AJAX. I've decided to make API controllers that handle every AJAX based request that the user is sending.

Should I use Passport as well because of the API calls?

What's the best way to authorize every registered/logged user to make AJAX based requests, without they have to authorize themselves manually?

Comment: use can use laravel default auth with api_token , no need to use passport

Comment: I have to use Passport, because I have a separate NodeJS server with sockets.io, that's why I'm using Passport.

Answer (score 2):

If you make those calls from a page which is already authenticated with Laravel adding Passport is not needed, just add csrf token as documentation explains, https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/csrf#csrf-x-csrf-token.

Passport is needed if your site doesn't authenticate against Laravel, like if you have separate NodeJS based client site and Laravel is acting only as an API backend.

Comment: Yeah. Most of the requests are sent from pages that are already authenticated, but I also have NodeJS real time chat and I needed Passport for there.